# Order HtmlNodes Based on their position on the HTML Page (C# / XPath)

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

**Context:**

I am parsing the result of a Query on [this service](http://sintegra.sefaz.al.gov.br/consulta_empresa_pesquisa.asp), but the HTML with the result is a mess.

My goal is the build a "KeyValue" pair with each "attribute and value" shown as result of this query.

At the moment only one way came into my mind to solve it.

**Logic for Parsing:**

1. Select all the Attribute nodes
2. Select all the value nodes
3. Match their "indexes" on each collection built to build the Key Value Pairs

E.g: Attribute[0] with Value[0] -> (In this service, that would be "CNPJ" and "12.272.084/0001-00").

**Problem:**

Even tho i managed to find a XPath expression to fetch all the attributes nodes:

```
attrNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes ("//td[@bgcolor='#f1f1b1']/*/font[@face='Verdana']");
```

I could not manage to find one for the value nodes aswell, since there are different types of nodes that actually look the same when rendered by Html ( "b" and "strong" for example).

There are even nodes with different hierarquies that prevented me from using Wildcards ("*") on XPath to solve it (single  tag or two  tags nested for example)

**My Goal:**

1. Write XPaths to reach each different subset of nodes with values
2. Put all the nodes in a single Collection
3. Order the nodes of this Collection based on the position of each node in the Html (nodes that appear first on the HTML will be on the begining of the list)

Any idea of how can i achieve my goal ?

**HTML Sample:**

You can either give it a check [here](http://pastebin.com/TuBE29HX)

or Query yourself the service by typing : **12272084000100**  on the CNPJ textbox
and clicking on "Pesquisar". After that, you just have to click on the text "Companhia Eletrica de Alagoas"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please link to an url showing the HTML you try to parse?

Comment: Or, if what @alexn is asking for is not possible, a representative example of what you are trying to parse?

Comment: Sorry about that, updating Question now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found an Attribute that can be found on the "HtmlNode" class of the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) Framework that managed to solve my problem.

According to [this documentation](http://www.kbs.uni-hannover.de/~minack/beagle++/beagle-0.0.13.2-doxygen/d5/d8d/classHtmlAgilityPack_1_1HtmlNode.html) about the HtmlNode Class:

```
StreamPosition
Gets the stream position of this node in the document, relative to the start of the document.
```

Here is the output of my tests using a list of tables found in this very same Html Page (tables used for testing purposes)

```
// HtmlNodeCollection of Tables
tableNodes[0].StreamPosition
925
tableNodes[1].StreamPosition
1651
tableNodes[2].StreamPosition
2387
```

Ordering my list using this StreamPosition as parameter managed to solve my problem.

```
List<HtmlNode> OrderedList = valueNodes.OrderBy ( node => node.StreamPosition ).ToList<HtmlNode>();
```

Comment: @SimonMourier I Can't mark my own answer as answer yet. StackOverflow minimum time for that is 2 days from now. I will mark it, as soon as possible.